# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am using Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE in my web application and I would like to remove the dependency on aspectjweaver.jar from it. I don't use AOP directly and I certainly don't use AspectJ. But my application fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:510)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.sortAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:73)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:91)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
```

Is the any way to completely remove the dependency on aspectjweaver.jar ?

Comment: are you using maven ?

Comment: there's not enough info, can you show app config and pom.xml?

Answer (score 19):

I encountered this problem when using the `@Transactional` annotation on a class annotated with `@Component` in Spring Boot similar to: https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

The easiest way to fix it is to add the proper Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am also getting this issue when i use these anotations together but wasnt getting this error before i made some changes to my app but now I am. any idea whats causing it because i didn't even change code related to this class and if it worked without explicitly requiring dependency i would like to do so

Answer (score 3):

Adding spring-boot-starter-aop dependency would resolve the issue, if you are facing it in the springboot application.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to completely remove the dependency on
>   aspectjweaver.jar ?

No, you cannot. You are using Spring AOP. The Spring project `spring-aop` does have a hard dependency on `aspectjweaver.jar`. Read the Spring-aop [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-libraries) that clearly identifies it as a dependency.

Comment: "At a minimum you will need the following libraries to use the Spring Framework’s support for AspectJ LTW". I don't want to use Spring's support for AspectJ LTW. So again, why do you need this library? Why there is a class level dependency?

Comment: @Nikem, in your question you have tagged `spring-aop`. Do you use `spring-aop`? If you don't, you don't need aspectjweaver.jar.

Comment: Have you read my question at all? If I remove `aspectjweaver.jar`, then application crashed with above mentioned exception

Comment: @Nikem, how can someone answer a question without reading it first?  Read my previous comment again. I think you have not understood the point I was trying to make. I am trying to say that you are using Spring AOP which has a hard dependency on aspect weaver. If you want to get rid of aspect weaver, you need to get rid of Spring AOP first. E.g. if you are simply using the basic Spring (Spring context), you wouldn't need AOP or aspect weaver and hence you won't get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Spring AOP is syntactically an AspectJ subset, thus it uses AspectJ classes for parsing pointcuts. It also exposes AspectJ classes like `JoinPoint`, `ProceedingJoinPoint` and AspectJ annotations like `@Poinctut`, `@Before`, `@After`, `@Around`, `@DeclareParents` etc.

Comment: But why then `spring-aop` module does not depend on `aspectjweaver`?

Comment: But it does. Look at [mvnrepository.org](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE), it lists aspectjweaver as compile dependency.

Comment: org.aspectj » aspectjweaver (optional). It claims to be optional, but it is not. Without it an application fails

Comment: Not my fault. Maybe a copy & paste error, it is also listed as optional for spring-core. Maybe you want to open a ticket and get it fixed.